# XOR gate frequency generator

Tags: transistors, frequency, signal-generator

I was wondering if a frequency generator using only a XOR gate would be possible, and doable, since a XOR gate turns on when both inputs are different, and off when similar. So by connecting the output of the XOR gate to one of the inputs and the other input to + this way.
When the output is of it will turn on, and when it is on it will turn off.

In a simulation this worked. Note that the output will be read using a transistor or MOSFET, so current and such is not a problem. In the simulation I added a OR gate, however this can be ignored, and is basically a way for me to extend the wire so it is clearly visible.

**My main concerns**

1. The frequency might be very high, and I do not have a oscilloscope to test it.
2. The frequency will not (fully) happen and it will stabilize in an in-between voltage and thus not oscillate (this one has happened to me in some analogue circuits).

And as two possible bonus questions, how could one reduce the frequency (I have thought about using capacitors and resistors to delay switch a transistor, but simpler options (in required material) would also be nice. The other one is how to prevent the output from stabilizing to a certain voltage, since transistors are also analogue, so this problem might also occur there.

[image]

Comment: It depends on the XOR gate. Which kind of XOR gate you have in mind, as there can be several different types, with different implementations? Usually XOR gates are not used for oscillators, it is more common to see NAND gates and NOT gates used in oscillator circuits.

Comment: It would be better to define specs on what you want like 1 Hz to 10MHz switchable in decades with a log f control variable logic level which can be done with switched caps a pot and 1/6 th of a hex Schmitt inverter and variable Duty Cycle added with a digital to  sine , triangle converter

Comment: _”transistor or MOSFET”_ The T in MOSFET stands for transistor.

Comment: I plan on making my own XOR gate using transistors and resistors. the specific frequency range doesn't really matter, it is just to make a solid state oscillator, which is stable, and so should work with any type of transistor. so it is just for experimenting purposes, or diy projects.

Comment: @Justme I looked at the NAND logic table, and that would indeed be a simpler option than using XOR gate, especially since you would only need 3 transistors for it, the NOT gate oscillator looked a little more complicated, however after visualizing the NOT circuit, that was indeed a much more simpler cirquit as well, and it seems to be much more easy to tune. So I will probably start trying those 2 especially the NOT gate version since it has more than 2 phases and would suit well in another project I wanted to make to drive a brushless motor.

Answer (score 2):

**so by connecting the output of the xor gate to one of the inputs and the other input to + this way. when the output is of it will turn on, and when it is on it will turn off.
In a simulation this worked Note that the output will be read using a transistor or mosfet, so current and such is not a problem. in the simulation I added a OR gate, however this can be ignored, and is basically a way for me to extend the wire so it is clearly visible.**

Almost. Your characterization of the XOR gate behavior is correct, but in real life your simulation might or might not work. It depends on how the OR gate responds to having an input float. Your simulator treats a floating input as if it is grounded. TTL and LSTTL gates will respond by considering a floating gate to be high, and your  oscillator will not work. CMOS gates will behave vary strangely to a floating input, and it's impossible to tell how this will behave.

**my main concerns are the following: 1 the frequency might be very high, and I do not have a oscilloscope to test it. 2 the frequency will not (fully) happen and it will stabilize in an in-between voltage and thus not oscillate(this one has happened to me in some analogue circuits).**

Both concerns are valid. If the XOR gate has propagation delay of 10 nsec, it will oscillate at 50 MHz.

As a bit of terminology, what you have is the simplest form of ring oscillator, with a single inverter. The OR gate delays the output and slows the oscillation rate. For both XOR and OR gates having a 10 nsec delay, the oscillation frequency will be 25 MHz.

**And as two possible bonus questions, how could one reduce the frequency(I have thought about using capacitors and resistors to delay switch a transistor, but simpler options(in required material) would also be nice.**

The answer is (in principle) simple - increase the delay from input to output. Er, actually, from the input to the input. In your circuit you have unwittingly done that with your OR gate. An RC version would be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkB0uk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, if you were using CMOS, and ignoring the fact that the input is now effectively floating, you would get a frequency of about 2/3 of a Hertz, which would be clearly visible.

**the other one is how to prevent the output from stabilizing to a certain voltage, since transistors are also analogue, so this problem might also occur there.**

The solution to both issues is the same. Detect the capacitor state with a detector which has hysteresis, or "snap action". This is generally called, in logicland, a Schmitt Trigger. These normally come as inverters, so the simple version would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP08zl.png)</sup>

This, as it happens, won't work. The inverting action of the XOR is cancelled by the inverter. What to do? The obvious answer is to add another inverter, but you can do better. All you have to do is drive the XOR with a LOW input, and all will work out.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXyCkk.png)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, logic gates with outputs fed back to inputs can stabilize rather than oscillate. An inverter in many logic families will often refuse to oscillate - even buffered inverters:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft5WZ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, a ring oscillator string of 3 inverters, or 5, 7, 9.... will oscillate. More inverters run at lower frequency. RC networks can slow oscillations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMdClw.png)</sup>

Another option uses a quarter-wave transmission line to select oscillating frequency. In this example, twisted pair transmission line is used with far end shorted. Length of transmission line determines oscillating frequency. When cut too short, oscillation ceases since is would be at too-high frequency. Not appropriate below a few megahertz, since transmission line becomes unwieldy-long. You might think shorted logic gates would stabilize at half-supply, but no: it oscillates:[image: transmission line oscillator]

 An alternate version of the transmission-line oscillator uses a continuous-loop transmission line wired in Mobius fashion. A number of inverter pairs spread over its length provide oscillation. Their input/output pins should connect to nearly opposing points on the line:[image: Mobius oscillator]

Comment: Nice answer not as simple as a Hex Schmitt Trigger and a pot with a 200:1 ratio in any range.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'd agree that Schmitt RC oscillator is conceptually-simple. OP wanted low-parts-count oscillator....hard to beat inverters+T-line. Have also done an LC resonator + one inverter type oscillator. Inductor is tapped. I'd call that 3-component oscillator. No bias resistors if you use a HCMOS inverter. Its high-Q gives a fairly low-noise result.

Answer (score 1):

> since a XOR gate turns on when both inputs are different, and off when similar. so by connecting the output of the xor gate to one of the inputs and the other input to + this way.

That's an inverter! Yes, inverter logic is commonly implemented with XOR when XORs happen to be the technologically available gates.

> when the output is of it will turn on, and when it is on it will turn off.

That's a *ring oscillator*. Typically, you want to have multiple (odd number) inverters in the ring, so that the you're not constantly driving the input around the "switch on/off" point, because of course the output slope is not infinitely steep, and while it rises, you might already be stopping its rise by crossing the input threshold.